# Install Subliminal through cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, cocoapods, subliminal

How to install Subliminal through cocoa pods?? Please, help))) 
Need instruction how I can do that with test-example... Because after setup subliminal through cocoa pods, in my project at launch subliminal profile I have a problem - Log message show me "There are no tests to run"
Previously thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the documentation for installing Subliminal using Cocoapods. The message that "there are no tests to run" is actually great news—it means everything is setup correctly. All you need to do now are [write some tests](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/wiki/Writing-Tests).

Unfortunately, right now the wiki page on writing tests is more of a broad overview, but it should be enough to get started. Hopefully we can improve on that documentation, soon.

Edit: I just made a screencast covering [installing Subliminal w/ Cocoapods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf1nhwpYPWg) that should he helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you got that far with cocoapods and subliminal, perhaps your test files are not associated with your new subliminal targets.

Open Xcode and select one of your test class files. Once selected, open the right panel and look at the Target Membership section.  Check to see that your files are associated with the targets you created for subliminal. You should see a check mark next to the subliminal target.